# Wildcard in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was wondering how to check for a wildcard in a batch file

```
SET /p project=Enter project (XYZ_2016_123)
```

I need to be able to check if the variable project is in the format XYZ_20??_123 where ?? are two digits. Ignore the XYZ & 123 part of the input. At the moment I have lots of if statements to check if the year. But I was wondering if could be done with wildcards?

```
s=%project%
if not x%s:XYZ_2016_123=%==x%s% GOTO MAIN
if not x%s:XYZ_2017_123=%==x%s% GOTO MAIN
if not x%s:XYZ_2018_123=%==x%s% GOTO MAIN
:: etc.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this :

```
echo %s%|findstr /r "XYZ_20[0-9][0-9]_123" >nul 2>nul && (
  GOTO MAIN
)
```

[FINDSTR](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Comment: You can use regular expressions in batch files??

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest - yes, for matching you can use findstr command.

Comment: That's is awesome! Thank you npocmaka!

Comment: But findstr RegExes are rather limited. See `Help findstr` or [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)